# React useEffect hook leads to huge spike in Reads in Cloud Firestore

Tags: reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, react-hooks

I see a huge spike in **Reads** in Cloud Firestore from `0` to `9.4K` when I use the below code.

```
useEffect(() => {
  const getPostsFromFireStore = async () => {
    const posts = await getPosts();
    setPosts(posts);
  };
  getPostsFromFireStore();
}, []);
```

Here's the `getPosts` function

```
 export const getPosts = () => {
  try {
    return db
      .collection('posts')
      .get()
      .then((querySnapshot) =>
        querySnapshot.docs.map((doc) =>
          Object.assign({ id: doc.id }, doc.data())
        )
      );
  } catch (e) {
    console.log('Error in fetching data', e);
  }
};
```

Even though, I used `[]` as dependency in `useEffect` hook. Meaning, the effect should trigger only once when the component is mounted. Also, I tried putting `[posts]` in the dependency but made it still worse.

Can this be made better to minimize the calls that are going to firestore? Could anyone please help?

Comment: I don't see anything wrong with this.  Is it possible that the component is getting unmounted and then remounted?  We're going to need to see more code, I think.

Comment: Please edit the question to show the entire code - especially getPosts.  There should be enough information in the question so that anyone can reproduce the issue.

Comment: @DougStevenson Just edited my question and added `getPosts` function

Comment: What happens if you add logging at various points?  What's actually happening here?  How many documents are in posts?

Comment: I have 10 documents. @DougStevenson

Comment: And my other questions?

Comment: @DougStevenson I placed multiple logger points in `useEffect` and in `getPosts`. It displays only once and Reads count went upto `9.7K`. Whenever I refresh the app, i see the hike of `1K` range in Reads.

Answer (score 1):

A cleanup function to stop the function making requests will be a solution here

**SOLUTION:**

```
const [mounted, setMounted] = useState(true);
//This will be helping us in the clean up function that will make in useEffect

useEffect(() => {
  const getPostsFromFireStore = async () => {
    const posts = await getPosts();
    setPosts(posts);
  };
  //First run this will hold make a request to you fireStore
  if (mounted){
    getPostsFromFireStore();
  }
  //Now you cleanup by setting mounted to false so hinder that function to render again
  return ()=>{
    setMounted(false);
  }  

}, [mounted]); //Our useEffect will be dependent on mounted change
```